# How can I improve myself in English writing and speaking skill?

Tags: grammar

I want to be a story writer. So, I need to write the English language without grammatical errors. But, I don't know how to be fluent in English. I am currently doing my honors in English Literature. Please, show me the right way. Thanks

Comment: To be a story writer you need to learn how people really talk so you can make your dialog realistic. If your characters don't talk like real people, nobody will believe in them. So find some English native speakers and talk to them in English. Don't worry about correct grammar; English speakers don't use it and don't know it. Just imitate the way they talk (not the way they write).

Comment: “How to improve my English” is off topic here. https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> To be a story writer you need to learn how people really talk so you can make your dialog realistic. If your characters don't talk like real people, nobody will believe in them. So find some English native speakers and talk to them in English. Don't worry about correct grammar; English speakers don't use it and don't know it. Just imitate the way they talk (not the way they write).